# How to detect inflection point in a non-differentiable part of a curve

Tags: calculus

In a $W$ shaped curve, is the middle point a maximum or an inflection point? In that regard how to differentiate mathematically between a maximum (or minimum) and an inflection point at a non-differentiable point within a curve? Is the concavity changing in the $W$ curve. In my understanding its not, so it shouldn't be an inflection point. Plz help.

Comment: It's a maxima, since you can find smaller and smaller neighborhoods where the middle point is the maximum. For it to be an inflection point, you would need that for sufficiently small neighborhoods, there is always a point greater and a point smaller, as well as some differentiability condition.

Comment: @ignoramus : It's not "a maxima".  It's a maximum.  The form "maxima" is the _plural_. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given us enough information about the shape of the curve to say what the concavity is anywhere, so we can't tell where any inflection points are.

Suppose $a<b<c$.  If $f$ is continuous on $(a,c)$, increasing on $(a,b)$, and decreasing on $(b,c)$, then $f$ has a maximum at $b$.